# make loop for this

Tags: r

how i make loop to get sum for each of the names in the list and puts it in a new table like I did just the short way

```
allllcheack = c("dan", "david" , "zidan", "dasa")


df = read.csv(text="
Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday
dan,david,zidan,dasa
dasa,zidan,david,dasa
dasa,zidan,dan,dan
dan,dan,zidan,zidan")
```

And here's the code

```
results[nrow(results)+1,]= c((allllcheack) %>% extract2(2),sum(str_count(df, (allllcheack) %>% extract2(2))))

results[nrow(results)+1,]= c((allllcheack) %>% extract2(3),sum(str_count(df, (allllcheack) %>% extract2(3))))

results[nrow(results)+1,]= c((allllcheack) %>% extract2(4),sum(str_count(df, (allllcheack) %>% extract2(4))))

results[nrow(results)+1,]= c((allllcheack) %>% extract2(5),sum(str_count(df, (allllcheack) %>% extract2(5))))
```

The desired output is a table with the values

```
dan 5
zidan 4
david 1
dasa 4
```

Comment: I guess you need `stack(sapply(allllcheack, function(x) sum(rowSums(df == x, na.rm = TRUE))))` or `stack(sapply(allllcheack, function(x) sum(unlist(df) == x, na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: Exactly,
perfect thxx u best :D

Answer (score 0):

You can `unlist` the data and count using `table` :

```
table(unlist(df))
#  dan  dasa david zidan 
#    5     4     2     5
```

If there are other names in the data and you are interested only in `allllcheack` names we can do :

```
tmp <- unlist(df)
table(tmp[tmp %in% allllcheack])
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sapply`

```
stack(sapply(allllcheack, function(x) sum(unlist(df) == x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

---

Or another option is

```
stack(sapply(allllcheack, function(x) sum(rowSums(df == x, na.rm = TRUE))))
```